# Create Collection class which inherits generic default parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ienumerable

I would like to create a C# class outside a repository, which inherits all the default generic methods (Add, Remove All, etc). This following code works. My goal is to move List ShoppingCart outside the repository.

```
public class CartLine
{
    public int CartLineId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

**Following Code Works:**

```
 public class ShoppingCartRepository
    {

        private List<CartLine> ShoppingCart = new List<CartLine>();


        public IEnumerable GetShoppingCart()
        {
            return ShoppingCart.ToList();
        }

        public virtual void AddItem(int productid, int quantity)
        {
            ShoppingCart.Add(new CartLine { ProductId = productid, Quantity = quantity });
        }

        public virtual void RemoveItem(int cartlineid)
        {
            ShoppingCart.RemoveAll(l => l.CartLineId == cartlineid);
        }
```

**This Code Does not work:** "Error: Shopping Cart does not contain definition for ToList. "

```
public class ShoppingCart : List<ShoppingCart>
{
    public ShoppingCart()
    {
        List<CartLine> ShoppingCart = new List<CartLine>();
    }
}


public class ShoppingCartRepository
{

    //private List<CartLine> ShoppingCart = new List<CartLine>();


    public IEnumerable GetShoppingCart()
    {
        return ShoppingCart.ToList();
    }

    public virtual void AddItem(int productid, int quantity)
    {
        ShoppingCart.Add(new CartLine { ProductId = productid, Quantity = quantity });
    }

    public virtual void RemoveItem(int cartlineid)
    {
        ShoppingCart.RemoveAll(l => l.CartLineId == cartlineid);
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to implement the missing methods.

Comment: What does "the default generic methods" mean? Particularly the "default" part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this would help you.

```
public class CartLine
{
        public int CartLineId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

    public class ShoppingCart : List<CartLine>
    {
        public ShoppingCart()
        {
        }

    }

    public class ShoppingCartRepository
    {

        private ShoppingCart ShoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();

        public IEnumerable GetShoppingCart()
        {
            return ShoppingCart.ToList();
        }

        public virtual void AddItem(int productid, int quantity)
        {
            ShoppingCart.Add(new CartLine
            {
                ProductId = productid,
                Quantity = quantity
            });
        }

        public virtual void RemoveItem(int cartlineid)
        {
            ShoppingCart.RemoveAll(l => l.CartLineId == cartlineid);
        }

    }
```

I change the class to make it generic. The Problem I think is, that you make your make a generic list of `ShoppingCart` but you want to add `CartLine`.

I hope this help you.

Comment: @LakeFish84 sorry I dont understand. You want a way where you dont need to declare a new ShoppingCart?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you trying to move Shopping cart outside, but there are many problems with the code

1. You will need to define `List<CartLine> ShoppingCart` property in the `class ShoppingCartRepository`. Right now you are creating it inside constructor. That will not make `ShoppingCart` property/field of the class.
2. As mentioned below in the comments, `ToList()` is not part of the `List`. So you will not be able to use it unless you explicitly define it. But not sure why you need to call `ToList()` on a `List` element.
3. Also, you shouldn't inherit from `List<ShoppingCart>`, instead use interface - `IList<T>`. That will help you with mocking/testing.

More importantly I don't see any value add in what you are trying to do. If you can provide more details around that, may be I can provide more details.